# Whether Application in VBA Excel should be initialized somehow?

Tags: excel, vba

I inserted the following function

```
Public Function Avr(row As Integer, col As Integer) As Double
    Avr = (Cells(row, col - 1).Value + Cells(row, col + 1).Value) / 2
End Function
```

in VBA Excel as a module and it works fine when called from cell (row, col) as = Avr(row, col). Now I would like to use Application.Caller in order to retrieve row and col values from it. Although, addition of just two lines

```
Dim adr As Range
Set adr = Application.Caller
```

results in an error code, also VBA editor changes the first letter in Caller to be in lower case. What is wrong here? Do I need to initialize the Application somehow or use something like include or import statement?

Comment: This function has issues. `Long` should be used instead of `Integer`, and you're implicitly working off of the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: How did you try to use `adr`?

Comment: I did not try to use adr in this example, function stopped working just after adding these two lines. I started checks because my editor kept auto changing Caller to caller, in lower case, just after I typed it. In the final code I needed only Application.Caller.Address.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller that shows how to get information from the caller without getting an error.

Here's what I did to get row and column from the caller:

```
Function TestSum(a, b)
    TestSum = a + b
    Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
     Case "Range": v = Application.Caller.Address
     Case "String": v = Application.Caller
     Case "Error": v = "Error"
     Case Else: v = "unknown"
    End Select
    MsgBox "caller = " & v
End Function
```

When you create that function and call it from a cell, the msgbox will give you the information you want:
[image caller example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bum87.jpg)